# run nodejs app inside codeigniter application

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, codeigniter

I have a CodeIgniter application. For another service I have developed a Node.js app.

I have two questions:

- How can I run the Node.js app to corresponding websites port number?
- If I let it run locally, it is accessible through localhost:4000, but only via Chrome. When tried to access it via Firefox, the following error occurred which referrers me to [this article](https://mzl.la/2QQZdSH) from Mozilla.

[image: error]

Comment: NodeJs requires a totally separate server (one which can execute JavaScript, instead of PHP). So inevitably it will need to run on a separate port. But then I would ask you: how have you ended up with a situation where you have 2 backends (one in NodeJS and one in PHP)??

Comment: you can use curl to get data

Comment: @RiteshDhoke i tried. but curl is much more slower that i need.

Comment: @ADyson I tried to fetch data via fetch api that called from front end.

Comment: From article you linked : `In many cases, it is caused by a browser plugin (e.g. an ad blocker or privacy protector) blocking the request.`. Firefox is known to have sctrict privacy protection. See if it breaks on Safari (also strict) and Edge or IE (not so strict). If it is viable option try disabling some protection on Firefox.